# Vim delays in gnome-terminal after moving commands (j, k, ctrl+f, ctrl+b)

Tags: vim, emacs, debian, gnome-terminal

This is a weird problem. When I launch gnome-terminal and run Vim, it starts working fine, but after a few 'j's and 'k's it starts delaying on the movement. Sometimes to the point of needing to press the key a second time to kind of force the movement.

I though it could be a problem with my `.vim/`, so I removed the folder, but it didn't solve the problem (though it seems to have improved a little bit). I also tried to remove my `.bashrc`, but that didn't help at all. Besides, if I run Vim from a `xterm` (with my .vim and .bashrc), it works fine. What does that mean?

Note: It also delays when I run `emacs` in terminal mode.

Comment: Sounds like it's a problem with gnome-terminal, not vim or emacs. Perhaps you have some "key repeat" setting wrong in the gnome-terminal settings?

Perhaps you could "solve" this problem by using `xfce4-terminal` instead. It's basically the same thing as `gnome-terminal` but maybe it doesn't have this problem?

Comment: Could be. It is weird because I haven't notice this problem before and have been using Vim in this terminal for a while now (around a year or so). I guess I could try the `xfce4-terminal`. Is it much better than `xterm`?

Comment: You're welcome to use either, but `xterm` is an ancient program that hasn't changed much over time. It's meant to be a "terminal that always works". So it lacks common usability things like easy copy/paste, easy configuration, tabs, etc.

`xterm` isn't going to suddenly explode in your face or anything, but you might find it rather barebones.

Comment: I just installed `xfce4-terminal` and it does not solve the problem, unfortunately :(. Regarding `xterm` I had that impression, but I've been trying copy/paste and it is quite okay. Don't know about the rest, but I'll give it a try. Thanks for the comments!